# Technique for multi-language support of big static portions text in Django

Tags: python, django, multilingual

For small portions of text we use django standart {% trans %} tag

What to do with big texts such as FAQ, terms and other static pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [`{% blocktrans %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#in-template-code) templatetag you can use.

You could also write a simple templatetag yourself which includes anathor template based on the current language.

```
{% i18ninclude "faq/question1.html" "en" %}
```

Would include `faq/question1.en.html`. Here is the code:

```
import os
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simpletag
def i18ninclude(template_name, language):
    template_name, extension = os.path.splitext(template_name)
    template_name = '%s.%s%s' % (template_name, language, extension)
    return template.loader.render_to_string(template_name)
```

Put this in a templatetag library of your app. I also recommend to read the [documentation about custom templatetags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) if you haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [django-better-chunks](http://bitbucket.org/hakanw/django-better-chunks/wiki/Home). It allows to insert snippets of static HTML inside your templates and it has i18n support.

For static pages I recommend to use some kind of CMS, for example [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org/). It's also i18n-enabled.